# jqgrid number formatter with separator and scale values

Tags: jqgrid

Using the number formatter like below to format the JQgrid number with decimalSeparator(,)& decimalPlaces(2)

formatter: 'number', formatoptions :{decimalSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces:2}

after enter the value as 134,56 in grid it was showing as 'NaN'.

please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which editing module is used and which version of jqGrid?

Comment: Using jqGrid version 4.8.2

Comment: Please specify  the editing module - inline edit, form edit or cell edit

Comment: using form edit

Comment: Sorry to ask again - is your datatype local or you save to the server.  There are a couple of things that you will need to take in account. By example if you save in server does your server accept this numeric value?

Comment: While saving into database removing the separator just saving the number while displaying adding the separator at scaled position.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to display correct the number in case you save to database is to set reloadAfterSubmit to true in navigator or in editGridRow method like this

```
$("#jqGrid").navGrid("#jqGridPager",{ edit: true, add: true },
    // edit options 
    { reloadAfterSubmit : true },
    // add options 
    { reloadAfterSubmit : true }
);
```